# Add Custom WPFControls to toolbox automatically

Tags: wpf-controls, addition, toolbox

I am trying to add a WPF control to the toolbox in VS 2010. I tried setting the ToolboxAutopopulate.This works only within the project. But i want the control to appear every time i open the VS irrespective of the project.

I tried making an entry into the RegEdit after deleting the tdb fils. It somehow doesn't appear in the toolbox still. Can somehow help me?? I don't know what i am missing. If someone wants to know more details i can provide.

The steps i followed were:

Close all running Visual Studio 2008 instances.

1. Delete *.tbd file located in your \Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 folder (for example: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0 in Vista or 7).
2. Add a new key to:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller

   or on x64 OS

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller

   The key is named like "QLeftPanel, Version=3.5.30729.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cd45d629e1d8d371", where you replace the WpfCustCtrl and PK token value with your own.
3. In the key created in step 3, add the following values:

   (Default) = "My WPF Controls"         This is the toolbox tab name, String
   CodeBase = "C:\Users\Aneesh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\QSharedLibrary\QSharedLibrary\bin\Debug\QSharedLibrary.dll"        This is the path to your control assembly.
   WPFControls = "1"          This is important!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing your control's `design.dll` and `visualstudio.design.dll` into GAC. then, take a backup of your existing tbd and delete the existing. Now, launch the Visual Studio, it will create the new tbd files. Now, It should load.

Comment: I am trying to add my controls.dll into GAC using gacutil.exe with administrator rights. I am not getting any kind of access denied error messages instead i am getting a message saying "Unknown Option: Studio" and the dll is not added to the GAC. Can anyone tell me what's happening??

Comment: When you add your `WpfCustCtrl.dll` , `WpfCustCtrl.Design.dll` and `WpfCustCtrl.VisualStudio.Design.dll` into GAC it should work. I never came across the above mentioned exception. Anyway check twice your signing process. Remember, You should sign all the three dll's.

Comment: Tip
`Type the commands manually. Copying and pasting the commands into the command prompt might result in Unknown Option errors.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w6bd8f1(VS.80).aspx